# Rails development is describe and show tables on all requests, how turn off it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, show

As you can see on rails log:

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-11 13:07:54 -0300 
  SQL (1.3ms)  describe `table1`
  SQL (1.0ms)  describe `table2`
  SQL (0.8ms)  describe `table3`
  SQL (0.8ms)  describe `table4`
  SQL (0.8ms)  describe `table5`
  SQL (0.9ms)  describe `table6`
  SQL (0.8ms)  describe `table7`
  SQL (0.8ms)  describe `table8`
  SQL (0.8ms)  describe `table9`
  SQL (0.8ms)  describe `table10`
  SQL (1.2ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (1.2ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (1.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (1.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (1.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (1.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (1.2ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (1.2ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (1.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (1.2ms)  SHOW TABLES

This is making my application slow, what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails needs to do this in order to determine what fields are in your tables, or it couldn't make all that ActiveRecord magic happen. Without this you'd have to explicitly declare all db fields in your models, which would't be DRY. The extra start up time is a necessary cost of using any ORM.

Comment: but is there a way to make it faster?